# Wordpress Gutenberg FSE Annoying Inline CSS

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I'm trying to remove some CSS, which is added on the front-end by Wordpress. On last update Wordpress is adding class like this:

`<main id="app" class="wp-container-620d4049355bb wp-block-group">`

`<div class="wp-container-620d404934f13 entry-content wp-block-post-content">`

wp-container-620d4049355bb / wp-container-620d404934f13 for main blocks.

The problem is it's also adding some CSS:

```
.wp-site-blocks > * + * {
  margin-top: var( --wp--style--block-gap );
}

.wp-site-blocks > * {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.wp-container-620d4049355bb > * {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.wp-container-620d404934f13 > * + * {
  margin-top: var( --wp--style--block-gap );
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

This CSS have a conflict with my blocks, where I'm adding single classes for setting margin.

Does anyone could help me how can I remove that css? Or remove that class? Funny fact is that wp-container-620d42ff1d800 is different every page refresh.

Thank you!

Comment: What if you would target the not dynamic class? Like .wp-block-group?

Comment: My system is similar to "Tailwindcss", For my sections/blocks per settings I'm adding a class like ".mt-y", which add X rem padding-top. So single class is beying override by .wp-container-620d404934f13 > * + * {}.

One soluton for now I see it's to rewrite group and content block and just stop using it

Comment: I see the same weird behavior with twenty-twenty-two and FSE. Where do we disable these styles and where do they come from? It is driving me nuts because I don't know how to disable it. The styles remove my margins on my images: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/twenty-twenty-two-image-blocks-suddenly-have-margin-0-via-inline-css/#new-topic-0

Answer (score 7):

The blockGap feature, `var( --wp--style--block-gap );` is not enabled by default. If you enabled blockGap or appearanceTools in theme.json, you can disable it again by setting it to null:

theme.json:

```
{
    "version": 2,
    "settings": {
        "spacing": {
            "blockGap": null
        }
    }
}
```

See the theme.json reference:
https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/theme-json-reference/theme-json-living/#spacing

If you want to remove the `wp-container-random` and the generated alignments, margins, and flex styles, you can disable the Layout feature.
Add this to your themes functions.php or similar:

```
remove_filter( 'render_block', 'wp_render_layout_support_flag', 10, 2 );
```

And if you have Gutenberg active:

```
remove_filter( 'render_block', 'gutenberg_render_layout_support_flag', 10, 2 );
```

Source for the wp_render_layout_support_flag: https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/block-supports/layout.php#L142

Comment: I don't understand this answer. I use standard twent-twenty-two with the latest WordPress version and see these generated inline styles. They remove some margins on my images and I have no idea how to remove them. Since I don't have a child theme I can't edit theme.json or add any filters to a function.php. Any idea how to remove the styles? See the same problem here: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/twenty-twenty-two-image-blocks-suddenly-have-margin-0-via-inline-css/#new-topic-0

Comment: The first worked for me: remove_filter( 'render_block', 'wp_render_layout_support_flag', 10, 2 ); I'm using Gutenberg/the block editor.

Comment: remove_filter( 'render_block', 'wp_render_layout_support_flag', 10, 2 ); destroys my whole layout on a vanilla 2022 Theme with WP 5.9. Not plugins. Where does this css come from?

Comment: Marc, your question and use case is different from the thread starter. You are asking how to change the margin for a single block, while this question is about removing the styles.

Comment: No, I ask how to remove the inline styles and where they come from. It is exactly the same problem.